# Exponential of a linear map with kernel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Consider I want to exponentiate a $n \times n$ matrix $H$ which has the property of 
$H^{2}=I$ and as such $H^{3}=H$. So my idea is just to write

$e^{-itH}=\cos(t)I-i \sin(t)H$

Now suppose there is some $\psi$ such that $H\psi=0$. Obviously then $H^{2}$ is not the identity anymore on the full Hilbert space. Can I still write an expression sillar to the expression above? I am stuck after the series expansion of the exponential.
For Example if I have a Hamiltionian of the form $H=\sigma_+ 
\otimes \sigma_{-}+hc$ acting on the space of two spin $1/2$
then

$e^{-itH}=$
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
    0 & \cos(t) & -i\sin(t)& 0 \\
    0 & -i\sin(t) & \cos(t) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0& 1
\end{matrix}

and not

\begin{matrix}
    \cos(t) & 0 & 0& 0 \\
    0 & \cos(t) & -i\sin(t)& 0 \\
    0 & -i\sin(t) & \cos(t) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0& \cos(t)
\end{matrix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, your penultimate expression 
$$
e^{-itH}= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
    0 & \cos(t) & -i\sin(t)& 0 \\
    0 & -i\sin(t) & \cos(t) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the correct one, since 
$$
H=\sigma_+ 
\otimes \sigma_{-}+ \sigma_- 
\otimes \sigma_{+},\\
H^2\neq H.
$$
In your example, the three blocks 1,2,1 split as block matrices, (for which mathematicians might have all sorts of Cartesian product alternative notations),
$$
H= 0\oplus \sigma_1 \oplus 0, \\
H^2= 0\oplus 1\!\! 1  \oplus 0,
$$
and the first and last 1d spaces transform like singlets, trivially, maintaining the nullity of your two null vectors;  while the middle 2d space like a binary doublet, so obeying your generic Euler formula.